# How to create a custom repeating reminder?

Tags: reminders, iphone, ios

I want a reminder that goes off on Mon, Tue, Wed and Thu at 5pm.  I haven't found a way to do that.  I can ask Siri to do a reminder on Weekdays, but that includes Friday.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Reminders doesn't seem to have this functionality at the moment. However, you can set an alarm in the Clock app that will go off at 5pm (or your chosen time) and you can select specific days like Mon, Tues, Wed, and Thu.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same Peoblem my Solution was to use an alarm clock instead of a Reminder